# Gaming on Ubuntu - How far can you take it?

Tags: games

I'm looking in to gaming on Ubuntu (using PlayOnLinux - i.e. wine). What is the most modern game you have run at an acceptable framerate and what hardware were you running? Did you have to tweak your wine or gfx card settings? If so, how?

Comment: Personally, I've run Team Fortress 2 on an Phenom II X4 810 with 6 gig of ram and a 9600GT gfx card. It ran well, but every few minutes if would lock up for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I think this should be flagged "community wiki", as you're asking for a broad report of experiences and opinions: there is likely no single answer that can be considered as "the valid one".

Comment: Oli was able to give a complete and concise answer instead of turning this into a giant unnecessary list question.

Comment: [blush] at the "giant unnescessary" (hope you meant the lists) and +1 on the surprise at a concise, useful answer. I couldn't find a 'community wiki' tag, so I tagged it 'community' instead. Please let me know if this was wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Before everybody lists out every single game they've played on Ubuntu through Wine, check [appdb](http://appdb.winehq.org) for specific games you want to run on Wine. Some work at near-native speeds, some don't work at all.

However, the "most modern" games I own are Modern Warfare 2, Dragon Age: Origins and Fallout 3. All work fine on my i7 920 + Nvidia GTX260 but then again, I didn't buy them until I knew they would. In a perfect world, MW2 could run a little faster.

Dragon Age and Fallout both took a lot of wine-hacking to get working originally - They're somewhat easier now but I still patch in WinePulse to simplify audio problems.

For Source games (that is Valve, not the open- variety) like HL2, Left 4 Dead, TF2, etc, you'll find that things run pretty well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input. wine-hacking aside, if you can run those, I think I'm ready to blow away my windows partition! (After getting a new graphics card :/ )

Answer (score 2):

HalfLife 2, Left4Dead, Left4Dead2, Civilization V, Team Fortress 2 etc. with Codeweavers CX Games. Buy CX Games - it's a lot easier to use than wine and you will support wine development with your donation either.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was [MLB 2k9](http://2ksports.com/games/mlb2k9) which amazingly runs pretty much flawlessly in Wine. The frame rates are around 20-30% slower than Windows - but still acceptable.

The cool thing was that it ran in Wine *unmodified*. (No tweaks or fiddling around.)

*Disclaimer: I didn't test installing it. It was already installed when I tried running it in Wine.*

Answer (score 1):

**[Heros of Newerth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Newerth)** (HoN) - a team strategy game like Dota (WC3)

[image]

It has a native linux version and installer.

Great graphics and is very addicting.

You can play it with your "windows friends" too ;-)